# Entity Framework Core Database Table Valued Functions Mapping

Tags: stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, ef-core-2.1

I use **EFCore 2.1** Database First approach. I'm pretty familiar with SQL syntax and prefer build queries myself rather then leave this work on EF. I use **Table Valued** and **Scalar** Functions for querying the database.

I found this for **Scalar**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping

But unfortunately nothing about **Table** Functions.

Is there any way to force Visual Studio grab all Table Functions and Scalar Functions and Stored Procedures from SQL Server, when I run Scaffolding?

I was using LINQ to SQL **dbml** designer before. Everything was extremely simple with **dbml**. You drag from **Server Explorer** drop to **dbml** and boom, I can use SQL Function or SP like regular C# method.

[image]

Any chance to reproduce this in EFCore?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reverse engineer (aka DbContext scaffolding) support for it, but you can use `FromSql()` to query using table-valued functions. See [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#composing-with-linq).

```
var searchTerm = "EF Core";
var blogResults = db.Blogs.FromSql(
    "SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs({0})",
    searchTerm);
```

Comment: Yea, I knew about it, this doesn't work to me, I'm trying to avoid all SQL code in my C# project

Comment: In case it's not clear, this automatically maps the result into a `Blog` object from the `DbSet<Blog>`. That means you can also chain `.Include` off this and EF will populate other properties automatically as well.

Comment: the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975726/use-a-inline-table-valued-functions-with-linq-and-entity-framework-core) , possible duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Source : https://www.allhandsontech.com/data-professional/entityframework/entity-framework-core-advanced-mapping/

Use **HasDbFunction** to do a mapping, refer [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalmodelbuilderextensions.hasdbfunction?view=efcore-5.0)

It requires return types to be declared as Keyless entity using **HasNoKey**[Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.hasnokey?view=efcore-5.0)

Configure EF Context to expose Db function

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(SalesContext)
    .GetMethod(nameof(NameAndTotalSpentByCustomer)))
    .HasName("CustomerNameAndTotalSpent");

modelBuilder.Entity<CustWithTotalClass>().HasNoKey();
```

Invoke Db function in calling code

```
_context.NameAndTotalSpentByCustomer().Where(c=>c.TotalSpent>100).ToList();
```

Generated SQL

```
SELECT [c].[Name], [c].[TotalSpent]
FROM [dbo].[CustomerNameAndTotalSpent]() AS [c]
WHERE [c].[TotalSpent] > 100
```