# Use a Inline Table-Valued Functions with Linq and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-core-2.1

I created an Inline Table-Valued Functions (ITVF) in SQL Server that returns a table of values (query simplified for discussion purposes):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.VehicleRepairStatus()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN
       SELECT VehicleID, CurrentStatus 
       FROM VehicleRepairHistory
       ...
```

Which I can reference in a query:

```
SELECT   
    v.ID, v.Name,
    r.CurrentStatus
FROM  
    Vehicle v
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.VehicleRepairStatus() r on v.ID = r.VehicleID
```

I'd like to be able to use it in Linq query:

```
var vehicles = await _databaseContext.Vehicles
    .Join() // join ITVF here?
    .Where(v => v.Type == 'Bus' )
    .OrderBy(v => v.Name)
    .ToAsyncList();
```

At some point, I may change the ITVF to include a parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.VehicleRepairStatus(@id AS INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

  SELECT VehicleID, CurrentStatus 
  FROM   VehicleRepairHistory
  ...
  WHERE  VehicleID = @id
```

And call like a scalar:

```
SELECT   v.ID, v.Name
        ,(SELECT val FROM dbo.VehicleRepairStatus(v.ID)) AS CurrentStatus
FROM  Vehicle v
```

Linq query:

```
var vehicles = await _databaseContext.Vehicles
    .Select( )  // call ITVF here?
    .Where(v => v.Type == 'Bus' )
    .OrderBy(v => v.Name)
    .ToAsyncList();
```

Is either approach possible?

Answer (score 28):

Yes, it's possible by utilizing the EF Core 2.1 introduced [query types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) (starting from EF Core 3.0, consolidated with entity types and now called **keyless entity types**). Following are the required steps:

First, create a class to hold the TVF record (update it with the correct data types):

```
public class VehicleRepairStatus
{
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    public int CurrentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Then register it in your `OnModelCreating`:

EF Core 2.x:

```
modelBuilder.Query<VehicleRepairStatus>();
```

EF Core 3.x:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VehicleRepairStatus>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

Then expose it from your db context using a combination of `Query` and `FromSql` methods (EF Core 2.x):

```
public IQueryable<VehicleRepairStatus> VehicleRepairStatus(int id) => 
    Query<VehicleRepairStatus>().FromSql($"select * from VehicleRepairStatus({id})");
```

or `Set` and `FromSqlInterpolated` (EF Core 3.x):

```
public IQueryable<VehicleRepairStatus> VehicleRepairStatus(int id) => 
    Set<VehicleRepairStatus>().FromSqlInterpolated($"select * from VehicleRepairStatus({id})");
```

And that's all.

Now you can use it inside your LINQ queries like any other `IQueryable<T>` returning method, for instance:

```
from v in db.Vehicles
from r in db.VehicleRepairStatus(v.ID)
select new { v.ID, v.Name, r.CurrentStatus }
```

The "select" inside `FromSql` method makes it *composable*, so the whole query is translated to SQL and executed server side.

**Update:** Actually this doesn't work when used as correlated subquery like the above example (see [Reference to an ITVF raises a "second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994531/reference-to-an-itvf-raises-a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a/52996678#52996678)). It could be used only if passing constant/variable parameters like

```
from r in db.VehicleRepairStatus(123)
...
```

See the answer to the follow up post from the link for correct implementation for correlated query scenarios.

Comment: This worked really well!

Is there a way to write the Linq query that will be performed to the console?  As the ITVF is in a different DB that primary model, I want to ensure that the query is being executed as expected.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you paraphrase?

Comment: When I use two DB contexts, it appears from the output that the second `from` is being executed repeatedly.  I'd like to see the SQL that is generated by Linq.

Comment: I moved the ITVF to the same DB as the `Vehicles` and modified the context to support it. When the code the `model = await results.ToListAsync();` line, it generates an error: `InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`.  Any ideas why this might be happening?  I assigned the query to a variable: `var results = from v in db.Vehicles ...`.

Comment: This sounds unrelated. Usually happens when you share db context instance between multiple threads. Check the lifetime configuration of your context. I personally always test with `new mydbcontext`.

Comment: @craig Please disregard my previous comment. It's my fault, I tested the approach with where, order by etc., but not the correlated query from the sample. It definitely doesn't work, I added answer to your follow up post. My apologies again.

Comment: can you provide where i can find this in microsoft's documentation ? please

Comment: @A.HADDAD There is no concrete documentation for this. Partially is covered by  [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) and [Raw SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: you could have used DbQuery<queryType> instead of Query<queryTYPE>() in OnModelCreating ,isn't ?

Comment: yes you can use DbQuery<queryType> instead of Query<queryType>() , i tested it and it works

Comment: It seems modeBuilder.Query<> is now deprecated in EF Core 3. The warning is: "ModelBuilder.Query<TQuery>() is obsolete. Use Entity<TEntity>().HasNoKey() instead.

Comment: Actually -- looking more into this, there are quite a few breaking changes in EF Core 3.0 relevant to the question and this answer. If you plan to use 3.0 or higher, check the full set of breaking changes - documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#fromsql

Comment: @Mike It's hard to keep old answers up-to-date with their (EF Core) constantly changing concepts / terms / behaviors. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: Very nice solution!
Working as expected on EF Core 5.0 using your 3.x example.