# Mapping a queryable table-valued function with a User Defined Table Type Parameter

Tags: entity-framework-core, user-defined-functions

I’m using the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 6 package. With this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) I was able to map a queryable function to a table-valued function. But I would like to use a User Defined Table Type Parameter. Have not found a guide that explain how to do that with Entity Framework Core. Is that possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a Inline Table-Valued Functions with Linq and Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975726/use-a-inline-table-valued-functions-with-linq-and-entity-framework-core)

Comment: EF Core Power Tools can do this for you